# Intellij prompts Proxy username and password when opening up Intelij - Windows-7

Tags: scala, proxy

I am new to Intellij and I have installed Intellij on Windows-7. Whenever I open up Intellij, it prompts for proxy user name and password.

Also, I am trying to install Scala plugin in Intellij and it is not showing up any plugins. I believe it is because of Proxy server.

In Eclipse, we can set the proxy details in eclipse.ini file. I am wondering how to set it in Intellij.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Regards,
Jee

Comment: You must be running Intellij as an administrator for some reason, which will require you to enter a password.

Comment: If you spell IntelliJ correctly (two Ls) and search this site for *IntelliJ proxy settings*, you can find many existing questions here.

Comment: I have installed the same Intellij version on my own laptop and it works good. But, I am trying to install/setup the same on my office desktop and it prompts for username and password. Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: @Jee If the office desktop is outside of your control, your IT department may have specifically added password prompts on unrecognized programs.